# How Remove duplicate column value after JOIN in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, rdbms

I want to get data from multiple tables using join. 
Its giving unique rows, but the column values are repeated and 
I'm not able to remove the duplicate values, so how to do it?

These are my tables

TABLE A

```
A_ID    A_NAME      
-----   -------
1       ONE         
2       TWO         
3       THREE
```

TABLE B

```
A_ID    B_ID    CAT         
-----   -----   --------
1       1       CRICKET     
1       2       FOOTBALL    
2       3       HOCKEY      
3       4       TENISH      
3       7       BASE BALL
```

TABLE C

```
B_ID    NAME
------  ------
1       ASN
1       MARK
1       JOHN
2       JACKY
3       RAJ
3       SAM
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
A_ID    A_NAME  B_ID    CAT         NAME
-----   ------  -----   -------     ------
1       ONE     1       CRICKET     ASN
                                    MARK
                                    JOHN
                2       FOOTBALL    JACKY
2       TWO     3       HOCKEY      RAJ
                                    SAM
3       THREE   4       TENISH
                7       BASEBALL
```

Query :-

```
SELECT   A.A_ID
        ,A.A_NAME
        ,B.B_ID 
        ,B.CAT          
        ,C.NAME
FROM     A,B,C 
WHERE    A.A_ID = B.B_ID 
AND      B.B_ID = C.C_ID 
GROUP BY A.A_ID,B_B_ID;
```

Comment: Do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: I have allready done but i want to do it in db ?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY. Won't execute with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: ok but can any one help me how to do it with querry

Comment: I edited my answer, it's possible, but not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

It's <strike>not</strike> possible <strike>and</strike> *but* makes no sense in my opinion. You could make an output like this

```
A_ID    A_NAME  B_ID    CAT     NAME
 1        ONE    1    CRICKET   ASN
 1        ONE    1    CRICKET   MARK
 1        ONE    1    CRICKET   JOHN
 1        ONE    2    FOOTBALL  JACKY
 2        TWO    3    HOCKEY    RAJ
 2        TWO    3    HOCKEY    SAM
 3       THREE   4    TENISH    
 3       THREE   7    BASEBALL
```

using a very simple query:

```
select
  a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_id, b.cat, c.name
from
  table_a a join
  table_b b on b.a_id = a.a_id left join
  table_c c on c.b_id = b.b_id
order by
  a.a_id, b.b_id, c.name
```

You can easily parse this on the front-end. You could also use `group_concat` to concatenate the names with the same a_id and b_id to a comma-separated list.

If you insist (need to add an artificial id to be able to join the previous row):

```
set @rank1 := 0;
set @rank2 := 1;
select
  case when t2.a_id is null or t2.a_id <> t1.a_id then t1.a_id else null end a_id,
  case when t2.a_name is null or t2.a_name <> t1.a_name then t1.a_name else null end a_name,
  case when t2.b_id is null or t2.b_id <> t1.b_id then t1.b_id else null end b_id,
  case when t2.cat is null or t2.cat <> t1.cat then t1.cat else null end cat,
  t1.name
from
  (select
    a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_id, b.cat, c.name, @rank1 := @rank1 + 1 as rank
  from
    table_a a join
    table_b b on b.a_id = a.a_id left join
    table_c c on c.b_id = b.b_id
  order by
    a.a_id, b.b_id, c.name
  ) t1 left join
  (select
    a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_id, b.cat, c.name, @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as rank
  from
    table_a a join
    table_b b on b.a_id = a.a_id left join
    table_c c on c.b_id = b.b_id
  order by
    a.a_id, b.b_id, c.name
  ) t2 on t2.rank = t1.rank
order by
  t1.rank
;
```

Comment: That would be so much easier in the application code!